# The host is taking longer than expected to start - Azure function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

When i run my azure functions in my visual studio 2015 it gives the below error.

```
The host is taking longer than expected to start.
```

I am using the precompiled azure functions, as explained in https://blog.kloud.com.au/2017/05/03/precompiled-azure-functions-revisited/

Any direction atleast to see some output on what it is waiting for, is highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think VS2015 is supported

Comment: It perfectly works in other project in same solution

Comment: Are you running multiple Function Apps at the same time?

Comment: One function at a time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my appsettings.json

`AzureStorage , AzureWebJobsStorage, AzureWebJobsDashboard` 's

connection string was invalid in **Values** Field. Hope this is useful for someone who has the same issue. Please **validate your host.json** and the **default properties** of the azure functions.

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=abcstorage;AccountKey=xxx",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxx;AccountKey=xxxx",
    "AzureStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxxx;AccountKey=xxxx",

  }       
}
```